# How to remove icons from Android studio editor which shows dependency between XML to JAVA and JAVA to XML?

Tags: android, android-studio

How to remove it in Android studio 2.3.2? "Go to related file" they are all the same.

[image]

Comment: Remove what? Please provide more description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto `View -> Active Editor` and Unmark `Show Gutter Icons`